# How to deploy Logic APP that has SQL execute sp action using ARM( Azure Resource manager)

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I want to deploy Logic APP using ARM. This Logic APP has "SQL Execute SP" actions. I found few quickstart template on azure blogs. But none of them contain Action for "SQL Execute SP" Action.

Answer (score 0):

ARM deployments of Logic Apps allow you to define the App Service Plan and the Logic App container, but don't allow you to deploy the entire Logic App. Right now you can design / deploy from the Azure Web Portal (https://portal.azure.com/) or [build / deploy from Visual Studio](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-deploy-from-vs/) only.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean by "don't allow you to deploy the entire Logic App"?

Comment: If you look at what the ARM templates can do they are effectively setting up an App Plan and then defining the performance tier of the Logic App. They aren't, however, actually deploying a Logic App. Have a look at: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-arm-provision/

Comment: In the azure, there is a ARM that listens a FTP folder and moves to blob available. Is there anything similiar for Dropbox to FTP?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the ARM template which has SQL action in it from another [stackoverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242019/deploying-a-logic-app-using-arm-templates-powershell)**

Thanks to Harry for sharing this

```
resources:
[
  {
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01-preview",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "name": "sqlconnector",
    "properties": {
      "api": {
        "id": "[concat('subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', resourceGroup().location, '/managedApis/sql')]"
      },
      "displayName": "sqlconnector",
      "parameterValues": {
        "sqlConnectionString": "<sql db connection string>"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01-preview",
    "name": "[parameters('logicAppName')]",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "tags": {
      "displayName": "LogicApp"
    },
    "properties": {
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('workflowSkuName')]",
        "plan": {
          "id": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('svcPlanName'))]"
        }
      },
      "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2015-08-01-preview/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "parameters": {
          "$connections": {
            "defaultValue": { },
            "type": "Object"
          }
        },
        "triggers": {
          "recurrence": {
            "type": "recurrence",
            "recurrence": {
              "frequency": "Hour",
              "interval": 1
            }
          }
        },
        "actions": {
          "Execute_stored_procedure": {
            "conditions": [ ],
            "inputs": {
              "body": null,
              "host": {
                "api": {
                  "runtimeUrl": "[concat('https://logic-apis-', resourceGroup().location, '.azure-apim.net/apim/sql')]"
                },
                "connection": {
                  "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
                }
              },
              "method": "post",
              "path": "/datasets/default/procedures/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(string('[dbo].[<Stored Proc Name>]')))}"
            },
            "type": "apiconnection"
          }
        },
        "outputs": { }
      },
      "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
          "value": {
            "sql": {
              "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', 'sqlconnector')]",
              "connectionName": "sqlconnector",
              "id": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/connections/', 'sqlconnector'), '2015-08-01-preview').api.id]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```